# System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object apex test classes

Tags: unit-test, exception

The Below code is a test class where I get my null pointer exception
app Builder:

```
public with sharing class appmaker extends packmaker {
public override String buildpack(Object[] records) {
    PackController.Delete[] del = new PackController.Delete[]{};
        del = (PackController.Delete[])records;
    String packupper = '<table><tr><td>Sales #</td><td>Delete #</td><td> To</td><td>fro</td><td>upcoming</td><td>expected</td><td>Products</td></tr>';
    String packvalue = '';
    for(PackController.Delivery d: del) {
        packvalue += '<tr><td>'+packorder +'</td><td>'+d.contnumber +'</td><td>'+d.to+'</td><td>';
    }
    packvalue += '</table>';
    return packupper+packvalue;
}
```

}

Comment: Where are you populating the variable `lstDeliveries` used in `getOutput` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is thrown because del is Null at Line no 7 in ODCSVBuilder class

```
for(OpenDocumentsController.Delivery d: del)
```

Put a check at line 7 and update your code.

```
    if (del!=Null){
for(OpenDocumentsController.Delivery d: del) {
        CSVData += '<tr><td>'+d.RefSalesOrder +'</td><td>'+d.DeliveryNumber +'</td><td>'+d.ShipToParty +'</td><td>'+d.ShipToPartyName +'</td><td>'+d.DeliveryDateCSV +'</td><td>'+d.GIDateCSV +'</td><td>'+d.Product+'</td></tr>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope@salesforcesmarty..error occurs in test class

Comment: Yes, but this is thrown by this class, as the variable was blank. Did you try after updating the code?

Comment: Yes yes..there was one more fault too..@salesforcesmarty..got it now.